# Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") not working on some Windows configurations

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine

```c#
public float GetAxis() 
{
    if (inputDevice == InputDevice.MouseKeyboard)
    {
        return Input.GetAxis(this.buttonName);
    }
}
```

This code is working perfectly on my Windows 7 x64 PC. My Project Input settings are ordinal:

Input settings:

[image]

But I watched some videos on youtube where people playing my game. And they can't use mouse in it. Looks like `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")` and `Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")` has not returning proper values for them and they can't control camera in game.

Other input is working fine for them.
My Unity version is `5.6.0f3` and I can't upgrade to actual version because game's code is too complex.

How to troubleshot and fix it? I have not build for other platforms then windows x86 and x64.

Input object was constructed:

```
public GenericInput rotateCameraXInput = new GenericInput("Mouse X", "RightAnalogHorizontal");
```

To read delta mouse movement I am running this method in LateUpdate():

```
protected virtual void CameraInput()
{
    if (tpCamera == null || cc.lockCamera)
    return;
    var Y = rotateCameraYInput.GetAxis();
    var X = rotateCameraXInput.GetAxis();
}
```

Comment: Are u sure `this.buttonName` is `"Mouse X"`?

Comment: Of course. And it is working on my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update. It is not a bug. I've just missed something in my project. 
I have a script to control the speed of mouse-controlled camera and PlayerPrefs variable to change it. And, in some conditions, that variable was set to 0. But for my case, it has already been set to registry and on my PC everything was working fine.
Maybe I need to delete this question, because it has not provided enough data.

I found this [thread at unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/input-getaxis-mouse-x-always-return-0.135951/) There are some people who encountered the same issue on real Windows PC with different Unity versions and different mouse drivers.
This is an old Unity hardware compatibility bug. Looks like it can't be fixed other then upgrading Unity or using other Input system.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this issue myself while using an RDP session or some kind of remote viewer such as TeamViewer. Mouse X and Mouse Y read the output directly from a device. If the device is not directly plugged into the machine that the player is being ran on then the inputs will not be properly retrieved. I'm not sure if this is the case for you, but this is the only instance I can think of these not being picked up.

Maybe you should add a bit of code that gets the mouse position each frame and outputs the difference, this would bypass the Mouse X/Y inputs anyways.

Comment: Do you get this issue on "normal" PC witout RDP? I've added some code but it is pretty simple. I get X and Y and pass them to camera controller each frame in LateUpdate().

Comment: Sorry, I've never had this happen in a normal scenario. Mouse X/Y is the amount of movement that has happened between frames I believe. I'd suggest that maybe users having this happening are running at a very high frame rate causing the output to be much less if not multiplied by Time.deltaTime, however the Script Reference states that this is "Not frame rate dependent".

Comment: You are right, it must be frame rate independent. And my game is in 3d, with something like 1000000 polygons per frame, it is hard to get high frame rate in such conditions.